# How to duplicate data based on matches in two different columns

Tags: r

I have accelerometer data sampled at 12.5Hz. For one dataset (X1), I have compressed these datapoints down into 1 second intervals, but I now need to recombine it with another column (X2) (sampled at 12.5Hz) to generate an equation. I want to duplicate the values in X1 if the time data matches with X2

My files currently look something like this

```html
X1
Time                           Accx1
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5
2019-03-28 07:47:08            1
2019-03-28 07:47:09            7

X2
Time                           Accx2
2019-03-28 07:47:07            2
2019-03-28 07:47:07            8
2019-03-28 07:47:07            1
2019-03-28 07:47:07            9
2019-03-28 07:47:07            1
2019-03-28 07:47:07            1
2019-03-28 07:47:07            2
2019-03-28 07:47:07            3
2019-03-28 07:47:07            1


And I want them to look like this:
Time                           Accx1         Accx2
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             2
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             8
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             1
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             9
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             1
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             1
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             2
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             3
2019-03-28 07:47:07            5             1
```

Comment: Have you tried `merge(X1, X2, by = "Time", all = TRUE)`? It might be imperfect if `Time` is `POSIXct` (related to the potential for floating-point comparisons), you could get around that with some hacks (such as rounding to the millisecond or similar).

Comment: You might also be able to use `findInterval` or `cut`.

Comment: @r2evans, yep I've already tried merge, but it makes all my X2 values NA. Not quite sure how cut would be used to duplicate all the values I want, but I have already used it to compress X2 into 1 second intervals

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which are the classes of`X1$time` and `X2$time`? You can use `class(X1$time)` and `class(X2$time)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for a right join. This should work:

```
merge(X1, X2, by = "Time", all.x = FALSE, all.y = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`merge` (and therefore most `join`-like operators) may not work well when your time has sub-second resolution. This is related to anything floating-point (see [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) for floating-point in general), where tests of *equality* between continuous variables is problematic.

For this, I suggest lookups by-range. This can be done with [`cut`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/cut) or (my suggestion here) [`findInterval`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/findInterval). For this example, I've changed three of your `X2` times in order to show something interesting: namely, show some different matches and a no-match (out of range).

Assumptions: `X1$Time` is non-decreasing; `$Time` are of class `POSIXct` (and therefore potentially more resolute than "1 second").

```r
( ind <- findInterval(X2$Time, X1$Time) )
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2

### that "0" is a problem, fix it
ind[ind < 1] <- NA

X2$Accx1 <- X1$Accx1[ ind ]
X2
#                  Time Accx2 Accx1
# 1 2019-03-28 07:47:06     2    NA   # this is b/c the ":06" is before X1 starts
# 2 2019-03-28 07:47:07     8     5
# 3 2019-03-28 07:47:07     1     5
# 4 2019-03-28 07:47:07     9     5
# 5 2019-03-28 07:47:07     1     5
# 6 2019-03-28 07:47:07     1     5
# 7 2019-03-28 07:47:07     2     5
# 8 2019-03-28 07:47:08     3     1
# 9 2019-03-28 07:47:08     1     1
```

The `ind[ind < 1]` step is because instances that occur before the first `X1$Time` will get a `0`, which shortens the return value (error: `replacement has 8 rows, data has 9`). By replacing them with `NA`, at least the replacement vector

---

Data, munged a little (add/remove `_`) to facilitate read-in.

```r
X1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Time                           Accx1
2019-03-28_07:47:07            5
2019-03-28_07:47:08            1
2019-03-28_07:47:09            7")
X1$Time <- as.POSIXct(X1$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")

X2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Time                           Accx2
2019-03-28_07:47:06            2
2019-03-28_07:47:07            8
2019-03-28_07:47:07            1
2019-03-28_07:47:07            9
2019-03-28_07:47:07            1
2019-03-28_07:47:07            1
2019-03-28_07:47:07            2
2019-03-28_07:47:08            3
2019-03-28_07:47:08            1")
X2$Time <- as.POSIXct(X2$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
```